# Mean and logarithmic values for arithmetic function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

Define the mean value for function $f$ as $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum \limits_{n \leq x} f(n)$ if the limit exists denoted as $M_f$

Define the logarithmic value for function $f$ as $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln x} \sum \limits_{n \leq x} \frac{f(n)}{n}$ if the limit exists denoted as $L_f$

Its easy to prove that if $M_f$ exist then so does $L_f$ and they are equal, but the other way around is not true in general.

Let $F(s) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) n^{-s}$ for all $s>1$, and we are given that in addition $F(s)$ satisfy $F(s) = \frac{A}{s-1} +o(\frac{1}{s-1})$ for $s \to 1^{+}$ and $A$ is a constant.

In addition assume that $L_f = A$, and use this to prove that $M_f= A$ ?

Note : This question has been uploaded to MSE but without any answer.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  (I don't know how to do it, but that very precise condition with no context about where it comes from leads me to ask.)

Comment: Link to the post on [math.se]: [Relaxation to Mean and Logarithmic values for arithmetic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3598165).

Comment: @LSpice not a homework, i im intersted in NT and this question shows up in one of the notes in the subject i am reading.

Comment: BTW if you created two different MO accounts by accident, you can find some instructions related to merging [here](https://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: The linked question is essentially answered in comments.